# On topic or off?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Referencing: [What is a good Apple podcast to listen to on a daily basis](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1075/what-is-a-good-apple-podcast-to-listen-to-on-a-daily-basis).

Is this an "all things Apple" site or more specific to "power users" meaning hardware / software rather then simply "everything?"

Would "what color goes best with my Mac Mini?" be an on-topic question? What about "best places to meet other Apple users?"

Answer (score 6):

> Is this an "all things Apple" site or more specific to "power users" meaning hardware / software rather then simply "everything?"

It's anything an Apple enthusiast would enjoy, as long as it fits the Q&A format, and is on topic as defined in the https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq.

> Would "what color goes best with my Mac Mini?" be an on-topic question?

Per the /faq questions should be (mostly) objectively answerable, so ... no.

> What about "best places to meet other Apple users?"

A bit too localized, if you mean physically -- and "best" is very subjective, so ... no.

> What is a good Apple podcast to listen to on a daily basis.

It's not a perfect question, but I think it's viable:

- it is fairly specific "podcast, Apple fans, daily"
- it is of interest to apple enthusiasts
- it's not localized (podcasts can be heard across the world at any time)